# How to parse List of List maps Json in flutter to listview?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this json how to fetch it to a `ListView`?

```
{
  "Status": 1,
  "msg": "ok",
  "allitem": [
    {
      "itemcod": "000223",
      "itemname": "ABC SAUCE 12*620ML",
      "InvntryUom2": "كرتون",
      "cuont": 2,
      "ItemResult": [
        {
          "ItemCode": "000223",
          "UomName": "كرتون",
          "Price": 115.0,
          "ItemName": "ABC SAUCE 12*620ML",
          "OnHand": 0.0,
          "UgpEntry": 1,
          "UomEntry": 1,
          "BaseQty": 1.0,
          "AvgPrice": 109.9999,
          "validFor": "Y",
          "SalUnitMsr": "كرتون",
          "InvntryUom": "كرتون"
        },
        {
          "ItemCode": "000223",
          "UomName": "حبة",
          "Price": 115.0,
          "ItemName": "ABC SAUCE 12*620ML",
          "OnHand": 0.0,
          "UgpEntry": 1,
          "UomEntry": 2,
          "BaseQty": 1.0,
          "AvgPrice": 109.9999,
          "validFor": "Y",
          "SalUnitMsr": "كرتون",
          "InvntryUom": "كرتون"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://app.quicktype.io)

Comment: Have a read here https://medium.com/flutter-community/fetching-data-in-flutter-and-displaying-in-listview-ec1bb72af22c maybe it can guide you.

Comment: this malty  list i need only list (allitem) show to list view and other no need